# Clarification on Central Limit Theorem (Sample Mean vs. Sample Distribution)

Tags: sampling, sample-size, central-limit-theorem

I know the CLT says that as sample size (n) increases, the distribution of the sample mean has a mean that approaches the population mean and the variance of those means approaches (σ^2/n).  The way I have visualized this is that lets say you take 100 samples, each with 50 observations (n = 50), you will end up with 100 means.  You calculate the mean of the means and the variance of the means and the distribution of those means has mean = μ and variance = σ^2/50.

My question is, does this relationship also apply to the sample distribution itself, or only to the means of sample distributions.  For example, if I took **only 1** sample, with an observation size of (n = 50).  I know the expected mean of that single sample is still μ, but is the expected variance of that sample also still σ^2/50?

I've been reading a bunch and may have confused two separate concepts.

Thanks!

Comment: The Law of Large Numbers states that sample mean will be too close to population mean when n goes to infinity. The CLT states that the difference between sample mean and population mean follows normal distribution.

Comment: Doesn't really make sense to talk about variance of 1 observation. You would ask for the variance of the estimator, not the estimate, which is equal to the same formula.